# explicit or implicit vec4 in glsl

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, opengl-3

I found something interesting and I would like to understand it.

Using **GLSL** `#version 330`

type of `gl_Position` is `vec4`

These lines compile fine:

```
gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);
gl_Position = vec4(vec3(0, 0, 0), 0);
gl_Position = vec4(vec2(0, 0), vec2(0, 0));
...
```

Somehow:

```
gl_Position = (vec2(0, 0), vec2(0, 0));
```

raises:

```
error C1035: assignment of incompatible types
```

The Compiler was able to parse `(vec2(0, 0), vec2(0, 0))` without raising syntax error. I want to know what this statement means, I believe it is correct and has a different type then `vec4`.

**Question:** What does `(vec2(0, 0), vec2(0, 0))` mean in **GLSL**?

**EDIT:**

*Compiles:*

```
 float x = (0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 8.0);
```

*Syntax error:*

```
 float x = 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 8.0;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the [*comma operator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), creating one `vec2` and then another `vec2` and it's the last `vec2` that is the result of the expression.

Comment: why exactly? is this standard? is there any reasons why this is allowed?

Comment: @DombiSzabolcs The [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) is a standard operator in all C-based languages, which includes GLSL. It's used to sequence expressions.

Comment: now I understand what is happening but still do not understand why is this allowed. I pasted another example.

Comment: @DombiSzabolcs Your new problem has to do with how initialization is parsed and handled. Try doing e.g. `float x; x = 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 8.0;` instead.

Comment: @Mars page 107: The sequence ( `,` ) operator that operates on expressions by returning the type and value of the rightmost
expression in a comma separated list of expressions. All expressions are evaluated, in order,
from left to right.